# Rails rel nofollow link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nofollow

I need to create no follow links with `link_to`.

I'm looking for something like this:

`<%= link_to "example", example_path, :target => "_blank" %>`

But for no follow of course.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can specify other attribues with link_to:

```
<%= link_to "example", example_path, rel: 'nofollow' %>
```

Produces:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="example_path">example</a>
```

Comment: NB that if you are passing in arguments then you may need something like extra braces:  `<%= link_to 'example', {:controller => :controller_name, :action => :ask,  :param1 => "setting"}, :rel => 'nofollow' %>`